# How to solve this multithreading problem in server-client architeture with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am working on a client-server architecture and developing a simple game.
It happens the logic of the game is running in the server. The way I identify the client is with their port(as I m running locally every client runs in my machine however in different terminals). As supposed every client should have their unique port, one per client(terminal). In my program, a client's port is changing and that impacts my whole game because the way I identify them.

```
while True:
     client_sock, address = server.accept()
     print ('Accepted connection from {}:{}'.format(address[0], address[1]))
     #adress[0] = local ip ---  adress[1] = port
     #timer = threading.timer(30,increase_energy(players_list))
     client_handler = threading.Thread(
     target=handle_client_connection,
     args=(client_sock,address,) 
)
     client_handler.start()
     #timer.start()
```

Comment: Doesn’t sound like a ‘multithreading’ problem. So you can’t use the client port. So you have to use something else perhaps you should identify the client by the server object that connects to it?

Comment: I don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: When you say "identify", do you mean over several different connections? Because it seems very perilous to expect a client connecting at different times to always have the same port. I'll echo the other commenters that it's not clear what you're asking for. Your issue has nothing to do with multi-threading, but with how you identify players. Perhaps they should log in or something?